# If we have a triangle floating in $\mathbb{R}^3$, can we calculate the surface area based on projections to the $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$ planes?

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, projective-geometry

If we have a triangle floating in $\mathbb{R}^3$, can we calculate the surface area based on projections to the $(x,y)$ and $(y,z)$ planes?

I ask this because I'm studying exterior forms at the moment and am trying to understand why any $k$ form can be written as a linear combination of $x_{i_1} \wedge .... \wedge x_{i_k}$ for increasing indicies

Comment: You have all three coordinates then. Use the cross product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the cross product, you can verify that the Pythagorean Theorem generalizes to tell you that 
$$A^2 = A_{xy}^2 + A_{xz}^2 + A_{yz}^2,$$
where $A$ is the area of the (tilted) parallelogram and the other three are the areas of the respective projections.

This is actually an equation relating norms of $2$-vectors (the wedge products of $2$ vectors), and there's an analogous equation relating the norms of $k$-vectors (the wedge products of $k$ vectors).

Comment: But OP has asked about the two-projection problem.

Comment: @Lubin, yes, I realize that. The other answer shows that is not possible, but I was trying to provide extra information. Perhaps it is better said in a long comment.

Comment: For the record, I do appreciate the extra insight

Answer (score 2):

Not if you only have two projections.

Consider a triangle
parallel to the x-y plane.
Its projections onto the
x-z and y-z planes
will just be a line segment.

So the third projection is necessary.

Comment: Great, crisp answer!